# Variable undefined fuera de la función angular

Tags: angular8

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual hago una consulta a base de datos para recuperar el tiempo de refresco de la aplicación. Mi intención es usar interval para poder usar el método setInterval().

```
export interface propiedadesSolicitudes {
  valor : String;
}
export class AsistenciaComponent extends Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public propiedades: propiedadesSolicitudes[] = []; 
public interval: any;

private getTiempoRecargaConsola() {
    this.gestorWorkflowService.getTiempoRecargaConsola().subscribe((propiedades) => {
      this.interval = propiedades;
      console.log('interval ---> ' + this.interval);
      //Devuelve 30000
    });
    console.log('interval ---> ' + this.interval);
    //Devuelve undefined
  }
}
```

Alguna idea de cómo poder asignar el valor para poder utilizarlo fuera de la función?

Comment: Y cual es el problema o la duda?

Comment: no sé cómo asignar el valor para que sea visible fuera de la función.

Comment: Cuando te suscribes a una solicitud HTTP, ésta se resolverá cuando se complete, pero tú estás intentando hacer un `console.log('interval ---> ' + this.interval);` antes de que eso ocurra, por lo que `this.interval` aún no ha sido definido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ejecución del script no se detiene, por lo que esa variable se actualizará más tarde.
Puedes hacer las funcionalidades que sean dentro del subscribe().

```html
export interface propiedadesSolicitudes {
  valor : String;
}
export class AsistenciaComponent extends Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public propiedades: propiedadesSolicitudes[] = []; 
public interval: any;

private getTiempoRecargaConsola() {
    this.gestorWorkflowService.getTiempoRecargaConsola().subscribe((propiedades) => {
      this.interval = propiedades;
      console.log('interval ---> ' + this.interval);
      //Devuelve 30000
      // Aqui pones tus cosas:
      this.updateData()
    });
    console.log('interval ---> ' + this.interval); // Esto será undefined prácticamente siempre. Estás haciendo una peticion externa pero la ejecución de código continua.
    //Devuelve undefined
  }
}

private updateData() {
  //Llamas todo lo que se tenga que hacer.
}
```

Comment: FUNCIONA! Muchísimas gracias. Ahora ya me coge la variable fuera del método.